# Can you use JavaFX scenes (made in scenebuilder) in different projects?

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I was wondering if I can use  JavaFX (made in scenebuilder) scenes that are not in the same project or maybe a different package?

I've been searching for awhile but couldn't really find anything about this topic. Only about doing it in the same project.

I already linked my different project to the project I'm using but still I can't get it to work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You have not described your problem properly. Please read[link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You can, but it'll work only in your PC. If you try to run the project in other PC, you've to put those 'scene' in the same path as your PC's.

Hope, you'll understand.